# Swift 4.1 class attributes and son strings prefixed by 'some' (Xcode 9.3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently updated to Xcode 9.3 and with it Swift 4.1.

Since update I am now seeing the text 'some' in from of class attributes and string attributes (see example below):

**sample json string:** `some({"email":"test@test.com","password":"password","deviceID":"00000000000:0000000000000000000000000","userid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","username":"test"})`

Note the **some** at the beginning?

Another example:

I have a simple User object:

code:

```
    class UserBasic: Codable{

    let deviceID: String!
    let email: String!
    let password: String!
    let userid: String!
    let username: String!


    init(deviceID: String, email: String, password: String, userid: String, username: String) {
        self.deviceID = deviceID
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.userid = userid
        self.username = username
    }

}
```

And when I instantiate and iterate across the attributes I now get this:

> Attr 0: deviceID = some("00000000000:0000000000000000000000000")
>
> Attr 1: email = some("test@test.com")
>
> Attr 2: password = some("password")
>
> Attr 3: userid = some("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
>
> Attr 4: username = some("test")
>
> Again note the text **some** at the start of the values?!?

This has started since updating to Swift 4.1 with Xcode 9.3

Its screwing up api calls etc as now I have some bundled with any e.g. json encoding..

**(Update)** heres my user obj inky and iterate code:

```
let userObj = Utility.createUserObj(email: email!, password: password!)
let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: userObj)
        for (index, attr) in mirrored_object.children.enumerated() {
            if let property_name = attr.label as String! {
                print("Attr \(index): \(property_name) = \(attr.value)")
            }
        }
```

**Update 2:**

This is the code to generate json sample above:

```
let userObj = Utility.createUserObj(email: email!, password: password!)
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()

        let jsonData = try! jsonEncoder.encode(userObj)

        let json: NSString! = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

Comment: It looks to me like the Mirror output now shows "some(value)" for an Optional with a value, or "none" for an optional without a value. As dan says, this seems like a complicated way of making JSON from an object that's Codeable anyway...

Comment: Your use of `!`s everywhere is causing your problems, you need to be properly unwrapping optionals.

Comment: **Never** declare properties as IUO which are initialized with an non-optional value. If the implicit `Decodable` initializer fails it will throw an error. Remove the exclamation marks. And don't `try!`. Catch and handle the error. And don't use `NSString` in Swift unless the compiler tells you to do. And don't annotate types the compiler can infer.

Comment: Your code to create a JSON string from your object works fine for me. I get the expected JSON string. Are you sure your problem isn't something else, and you're confusing yourself with your reflection code/debugging output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue create the JSON string this way, implicit unwrapped optional is inappropriate.

```
do {
    let jsonData = try jsonEncoder.encode(userObj)
    let json = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
} catch { print(error) }
```

If the encoding of the JSON succeeds `json` cannot be `nil`.